# Validate form fields Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

I'm trying to make sure that in a "text box" I can only input specific characters , and or only numbers.
I want to to this with selenium , but I seem unable to reach the script throw selenium.
Im able to check the properties of the text box but not the script itself , since this one does not appear on screen.

Here is the code I want to check.
**How can I test the script through selenium?**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple form</title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        

        <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <form onsubmit="return Validted()">
                New user registration:<br><br>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            First name: *
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="f_name"     name="fname"  maxlength="128" value="" class="firstn"  placeholder="first name" style="border-color: gray"><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Last name:  *
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text"  id="l_name"     name="lname"  maxlength="128" value="" class="lastn"   placeholder="last name"  style="border-color: gray"><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Password:   *
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="password"  id="pass"   name="pass"   maxlength="128" value="" class="pass"    placeholder="password"  style="border-color: gray"><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Phone:      *
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="tel"   id="tel"        name="tel"    maxlength="15"  value="" class="phone"   placeholder="phone number"  style="border-color: gray"><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            E-mail:     *
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="email" id="user_email" name="email"  maxlength="128" value="" class="eml"     placeholder="Enter email"  style="border-color: gray"><br>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <input type="submit" value="Register">
            </form>
        </div>

        <br>password rules: <br>
        only 0-9a-zA-Z         <br>
        at least 8 characters <br>
        at least 1 number <br>
        at least 1 lowercase character (a-z) <br>
        at least 1 uppercase character (A-Z) <br>


        <script>
            var validEmail = /^\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*$/;
            var validPhone = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/;
            var validPass = /^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])([a-zA-Z0-9]{8})$/;
            function testThis(what, reg, fld) {
                if (reg.test(what)) {
                    $('.' + fld).css('color', 'green');
                    console.log(fld);
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    $('.' + fld).css('color', 'red');
                    return false;
                }
            }

            function Validted() {
                $('.pass').css('border-color', 'gray');
                $('.phone').css('border-color', 'gray');
                $('.eml').css('border-color', 'gray');

                if (!testThis($('#user_email').val(), validEmail, 'eml')) {
                    $('.eml').css('border-color', 'red');
                    return false;
                }
                if (!testThis($('#pass').val(), validPass, 'pass')) {
                    $('.pass').css('border-color', 'red');
                    return false;
                }
                if (!testThis($('#tel').val(), validPhone, 'phon')) {
                    $('.phone').css('border-color', 'red');
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }

            function validatePass() {
                $('#pass').keyup(function () {
                    return testThis(this.value, validPass, 'pass');
                });
            }
         }
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong. That's not what Selenium is for. You would test the script via selenium by attempting to enter invalid characters then looking for what happens when invalid characters are entered, as you are doing. If you want to just check the script is present there are other ways to do that.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the clarification!